# Print a single line the minimum number of operations required to complete the task

Tags: python, python-3.x

as you see i am stuck in the below python code to find the desired output. I got the the output but it is not 2(Which is right output.)

Anyone got some ropes. he want to make each of the rope as small as possible. The sequence of ropes has got some special property. Each rope has a unique length. The ropes are numbered 1 to N.
We can choose M sized subsegment of the sequence and cut all the ropes present in the subsegment to the length of the minimum length rope present in that subsegment.
The first line of input contains a single integer M denoting the size of the subarray we can pick in any operation. the next line contains a single integer N denoting the number of ropes. Then N lines follow where each line contains a single integer denoting the length of the rope

**import collections**

```
>>> class Solution:
'''Defining function for min operation'''
        def minOperations(self, sizeOfSubarray, lengthsOfRopes):
            #write code here
    ///writing code
    def main():
        R = input()
        R = int(R)
        k = input()
        k = int(k)
        res = []
        '''Using loop for input'''
        for i in range(k):
            res.append(int(input().strip()))
        ret = Solution().minOperations(R,res)
        print(ret)
    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
 
         
     '''//input
       4
       5
       2
       1
       3 
       4 
       5
```

//output
2

Comment: There is no need to instantiate the solution class, just declare it as a class method and remove the self

Comment: That method is good but answer required in given format

Comment: Nah i dont get what you want to do. It is very confusing to me, i just pointed out that if you want to encapsulate the method, it should be a class method not instance method

Comment: class has a method(Which has to be written for desired output) which called in the main function.

Comment: I know, but its supposed to be a classmethod, not an instancemethod

Comment: If you dont know what a classmethod is, you should check out how they work https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/classmethod

Comment: I Know what is class method

Comment: I dont understand, consider using a translator or describing what you mean to say